# Why send two HTTP requests When use 303 URIs

Tags: xml, uri, rdf

---

Part 1

GET /people/dave-smith HTTP/1.1

Host: biglynx.co.uk

Accept: text/html;q=0.5, application/rdf+xml

---

Part 2

1 HTTP/1.1 303 See Other

2 Location: http://biglynx.co.uk/people/dave-smith.rdf

3 Vary: Accept

---

Part3

1 GET /people/dave-smith.rdf HTTP/1.1

2 Host: biglynx.co.uk

3 Accept: text/html;q=0.5, application/rdf+xml

---

my question

why not set "GET /people/dave-smith.rdf HTTP/1.1" from the first in 'Part 1' instead of GET /people/dave-smith HTTP/1.1"

Answer (score 3):

Because `http://biglynx.co.uk/people/dave-smith` is the identifier of the given resource. Itself it doesn't have a representation but redirects to a representation based on `Accept` header.

You can `GET /people/dave-smith` and 'ask' for RDF, HTML, Turtle or `image/png` and the server will redirect you to an appropriate document (resource). Yet still there is only one identifier, because all those representations **represent** the same resource.

There are other options in addition to 303 redirect. You can read an in-depth discussion [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/)